# Is it possible to insert an animated image into Mathematica notebook?

Tags: front-end, import, notebooks, animation

I find it very convenient to use Mathematica notebooks to organize the codes + results.

I was wondering if it is possible to insert an animated image (say an animated gif) in the middle of a notebook.

I tried dragging and dropping an animated gif into a notebook, the gif itself was created using Mathematica. Mathematica imports it and I see a bunch of images in the notebook. This suggests one solution: using a `Manipulate` or `Animate`, with those bunch of images. But *is there a less tedious and more elegant way*?

Comment: Import["pp.gif", "Animation"] ?

Comment: fyi, I have asked the same question here http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Feb/msg00070.html `Is there a trick to embed an animated gif file in a Mathematica notebook? (The gif file do not have to 'run' while inside the notebook, I am only interested in the HTML export version` this was in `Feb 2012` but there was no answer. 
notebook?`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The credits go to belisarius and the Mathematica help ([ref/format/GIF](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/ImportAndExportAnimations.html)), but I thought the comment would be worth an answer.

```
Import["ExampleData/cellularautomaton.gif", "Animation"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately I don't know of any simple and convenient ways.

You can import the GIF first:

```
frames = Import["http://i.imgur.com/ivfdq.gif"];
```

Then you can use `ListAnimate` to get an animation:

```
ListAnimate[frames]
```

For completeness I'll mention that pre-6 versions could also animate. `Scan[Print, frames]` will give you each frame in separate cells.  Now close the cell group by double clicking its bracket and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Y</kbd> to start the animation.  This still works in version 8.

Comment: (Slightly OT): Is there some way to import the animated GIF and have it appear animated -- but without the frame and `Animator` element?

Comment: @murray Well, you can always hack together something manually ... `list = Range[100];
DynamicModule[{i = 1},
 Dynamic[Refresh[list[[i = Mod[i + 1, Length[list], 1]]], 
   UpdateInterval -> 1/4], TrackedSymbols -> {}]
 ]`

Comment: @murray Try `Dynamic@frames[[Clock[{1, Length@frames, 1}, Length@frames/30.]]]` or perhaps less satisfactorily `ListAnimate[frames, Paneled -> False] /. HoldPattern[AppearanceElements -> _] -> AppearanceElements -> None` -- Oops, I just noticed how old this is...oh, well.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one more attempt to get almost the exact appearance of an animated `GIF` without the playback controls. I don't recommend putting too many of these into a notebook, though:

```
makeAnimation[list_, delayList_: {.03}] := 
 DynamicModule[{l = Length[list], delays = Abs@Flatten[{delayList}], 
   times, totalTime, delta = .03, frames}, 
  times = Round[.5 + PadRight[delays, l, delays]/delta];
  frames = 
   Flatten@Table[Table[list[[i]], {times[[i]]}], {i, Length[times]}];
  totalTime = Length[frames];
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic[frames[[Clock[{1, totalTime, 1}, totalTime delta]]], 
    TrackedSymbols -> {}], {"MouseUp", 2} :> Null]]

makeAnimation[
 Import["ExampleData/cellularautomaton.gif", "ImageList"]]
```

[image: gif]

You can copy this animation by selecting its cell bracket. It's persistent across notebooks, too.

Comment: Pretty slick. +1

Comment: Nice. But the animation is not seen in the HTML exported file. That is what I really wanted all along. Here is screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EKuwb.png)  and here was my original question on this http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2012/Feb/msg00070.html  it would be nice if M can use the animation as animated gifs when exporting to HTML and also PDF (since PDF can have animations in them these days).