# How can I completely remove the ListAnimate controls?

Tags: graphics, bugs, animation, gui-construction

I want to use `ListAnimate` to show an animation but I want to remove the slider and all of the buttons from the top and show the animation panel only. There is an `AppearanceElements -> None` option but it doesn't remove the slider and the other buttons. How can I remove all of the controls?

Comment: Just a note: `ControlType->None` will do this but there will be no animation but only a rasterized image.

Comment: Closely related: [Is it possible to insert an animated image into Mathematica notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3037/245)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at underlying code:

```
ListAnimate[Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 25}]] // InputForm
```

at the end you'll find:

[image]

which leads to a trick:

```
ListAnimate[Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 25}]] /. 
 HoldPattern[AppearanceElements -> _] -> (AppearanceElements -> None)
```

[image]

In the spirit of @Mr.Wizard comment you can also do something like:

```
ListAnimate[Table[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 10}], {n, 25}], 
  Paneled -> False] /. (AppearanceElements -> _) -> (AppearanceElements -> {})
```

which a bit changes things.

Comment: Nice trick.  You don't need `HoldPattern` by the way.  This still leaves the space for the controls; can you remove that too?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks :) hmmm... not sure about space. I added something at the end of the answer.

Comment: If you cannot apply `AppearanceElements->None` directly as an option, surely that must be a bug?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I'll see what I can find out.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** go through the `list` every 2 seconds and stop after 5 repetitions:

```
list = Table[Plot[Sin[x + n], {x, 0, 3 Pi}, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}], {n, -2 Pi, 2 Pi, Pi/40}];

Dynamic[list[[Clock[{1, Length@list, 1}, 2, 5]]]]
```

[image]

---

**Original post:**

Since

> `ListAnimate` generates a `Manipulate` object containing an `Animator` ([docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListAnimate.html))

With explicit lists as input, say,

```
 list = Table[Plot[Sin[x + n], {x, 0, 3 Pi}], {n, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}];
```

the animation produced by `ListAnimate[list...]` can also be produced using `Manipulate` or `Animator` specifying the `Animator` option settings directly (instead of post-processing the `Manipulate` object generated by `ListAnimate`).

```
Manipulate[list[[k]], {{k, 1, ""}, 1, Length[list], 1,
      ControlType -> Animator, AnimationRate -> 15, 
      AnimationRunning -> True, AppearanceElements -> {}},
  AppearanceElements -> None, Paneled -> False]
```

or

```
DynamicModule[{j},
  Column[{Animator[Dynamic[j], {1, Length@list, 1}, 15, 
       AnimationRunning -> True, AppearanceElements -> None], 
  Dynamic[list[[j]]]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is impressive as the file size is dramatically reduced, at least in my case working with `DensityPlot` +1.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do that.  Perhaps you are open to an alternative?

```
animate[list_List, rate_?Positive] := DynamicModule[{x = list},
  Dynamic[First[x = RotateLeft@x], UpdateInterval -> 1/rate, TrackedSymbols -> {}]]

list = Table[Plot[Sin[x + n], {x, 0, 3 Pi}], {n, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/20}];

animate[list, 15]
```

[image]

Comment: It's too slow on my machine but it's what I am looking for. `ListAnimate` looks 10x faster to me. I want to make an interactive user interface, so being fast is a must.

Comment: @Mohsen Yes, I see now that it's not very smooth.