# how to draw a moving point on a curve?

Tags: graphics, animation

I almost remember an example that has a moving red point on a given curve, which will moving time and time again, with no controls...

now, here is my question: given a curve by

```
u[y_] := y^4 - 4 y^2 + 3
v[y_] := 2 y - y^3
curv=ParametricPlot[{u[y], v[y]}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

then, how to attach a "big red" moving point on it, which are moving again and again?

Comment: How do we decide which curve to put the point on at say x=0?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Animate`

```
u[y_] := y^4 - 4 y^2 + 3
v[y_] := 2 y - y^3
curv = ParametricPlot[{u[y], v[y]}, {y, -2, 2}];
Animate[
 Show[
  curv,
  Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Dynamic[{u[t], v[t]}]]}]
  ]
 , {t, -2, 2,AppearanceElements->None}]
```

[image: Animate None]

Comment: can I make it without controls?

Comment: @van, you could use `Table[]` in place of `Animate[]` and export as a GIF file...

Comment: @vanabel Try `Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5, 
  AppearanceElements -> None}]`

Comment: I really think you should review your last solution, what you are producing is the product of an invisible element and a graph, which is perfectly valid in Mathematica, but definitely not what someone reading the code expects. When you want to tie a dynamic expression to a different display form, you should properly use `DynamicWrapper`.

Comment: @jVincent, Yes I'll make it more clear :)

Answer (score 6):

A potential way of doing this is by using `DynamicModule` to keep a scoped variable time, and use Dynamic wrapper to keep it updated:

```
 curve

 DynamicModule[{t},
   DynamicWrapper[
      Show[curv, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[Dynamic[{u[t], v[t]}]]}]],
   t = Clock[{-2, 2}]
   ]
  ]
```

Comment: I like the use of `Clock` I couldn't figure out how to get it neat like that :)

Comment: Any way with `Dynamic` and `Clock` to do that yet have the point traverse the curve just once? Just as `AnimationRepetitions -> 1` would do inside an `Animate`?

Comment: @murray Have a look at the [documentation for `Clock`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clock.html) it has a quite useful span of usages. to set it to only run through the animation once in this case, simply use `Clock[{-2, 2}, 4, 1]`.

Comment: @jVincent: Yes, I see that `Clock` allows running just once. It's just that I've always been annoyed that `Animate`, and the `Manipulate` animation control, produce a loop.

Answer (score 4):

You don't want to have controls? How about using timed tasks?

```
p=0;
t = CreateScheduledTask[p = Mod[p + 0.1, 4, -2], 0.1];

Show[
 curv,
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.03], Dynamic@Point@{u[p], v[p]}}]
 ]

StartScheduledTask[t];
```

Stop it using:

```
RemoveScheduledTask[t];
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `Refresh` to take care of the timing.

```
Show[
 curv,
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.03], 
   Dynamic[Refresh[p = Mod[p + 0.05, 4, -2]; Point@{u[p], v[p]}, 
     UpdateInterval -> 0.05, TrackedSymbols -> {}]]}]
 ]
```

Note the `TrackedSymbols -> {}` option which prevents the `p = Mod[p + 0.05, 4, -2]` part from self-triggering another iteration.

---

It's even easier using `Clock`:

```
Show[curv, 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.03], 
   Dynamic[Point@{u[#], v[#]} &@Clock[{-2, 2, .05}, 5]]}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to use [`Clock`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clock.html): with a [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) combination:

```
 Dynamic @ ParametricPlot[{u[x], v[x]}, {x, -2, 2},
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
  Mesh -> {{Clock[{-2, 2}]}}, 
  MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[Large]}]
```

[image]

Yet another way: Using `ListAnimate`:

```
 ListAnimate[Table[Show[ParametricPlot[{u[x], v[x]}, {x, -2, 2}],
    Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{u[t], v[t]}]}]],
    {t, -2, 2, .01}], Paneled -> False] /. 
 HoldPattern[AppearanceElements -> _] -> (AppearanceElements -> None)
```

[image]

(the trick to remove `AppearanceElements` from [Vitaly's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13024/125) to a related question.)