# Move a point along a curve

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation, splines

I am trying to implement the de Casteljau algorithm to trace a point along a Bézier curve.

I already have the Bézier curve in place given by the control points

```
pts = {{54.78, 62.24}, {26.87, 68.24}, {1.58, 63.24}, 
       {-1, 49.18}, {1.58, 35.18}, {28.57, 35.03}, {52.41, 35.03}, 
       {60.48, 22.58}, {52.4, 7.4}, {24.27, 2}, {0, 10}};
```

I have been reading up on the de Casteljau algorithm and I understand the basic implementation of it, but I don't understand how to manipulate the point to move along the curve using the algorithm.

Comment: You might want to point to the textbook you're using so that answerers can write something you can easily relate to what you're reading.

Comment: Do you really need to implement this algorithm on your own as opposed to simply using the built in `BezierFunction` ?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/how-to-draw-a-moving-point-on-a-curve

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by [george2079](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2079/george2079)

```
pts = {{54.78, 62.24}, {26.87, 68.24}, {1.58, 63.24}, {-1, 49.18}, {1.58, 
    35.18}, {28.57, 35.03}, {52.41, 35.03}, {60.48, 22.58}, {52.4, 
    7.4}, {24.27, 2}, {0, 10}};

f = BezierFunction[pts];

llp = ListLinePlot[Table[f[t], {t, 0, 1, .02}]];

Manipulate[
 Show[llp,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Point[f[u]]}],
 {{u, .5}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

EDIT:  In a comment, [yode](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21532/yode) suggested the use of [ParametricPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html)). This has the advantage of exploiting the adaptive sampling of the built-in plotting functions and is more direct (i.e., you don't have to generate the `Table` of points used with [ListLinePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html)).

```
pp = ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}];

Manipulate[
 Show[pp,
  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
    Point[f[u]]}],
 {{u, .5}, 0, 1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: `f = BezierFunction[pts];
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
  Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point[f[u]]}], {{u, .5}, 0, 
  1, .01, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: @yode - Use of [ParametricPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) is a good idea; however, since like the [ListLinePlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html) it is independent of the [Manipulate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html) control, I would pull the plot outside of the `Manipulate` and use [Show](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) to keep the interaction as responsive as possible. Recommend that you post this as an answer.

Comment: The honor should be attributed to you.I just wanna give a little advice to your answer.

Comment: @yode - edited per your recommendation.