# How do I animate a point and an position vector along an animated parametric curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics, animation

I have created the following animation:

```
Animate[ParametricPlot[{Cos[y], Sin[y]}, {y, 0, a},
  PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], {a, 0.01, 2 Pi}]
```

How do I

1. highlight the most advanced point on the curve (i.e. add another graphics point animation with coordinates dependant on the same a variable)
2. draw a connecting vector from the origin to the continuously moving point

Thanks!

EDIT: A similar problem is described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14736/how-to-draw-a-moving-point-on-a-curve), however the curve isn't animated. I would like the curve to be included in the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Animate[Show[
  ParametricPlot[{Cos[y], Sin[y]}, {y, 0, a}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}}], 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{Cos[a], Sin[a]}],
    Orange, Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[a], Sin[a]}}]
    }]], {a, 0.01, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Additionally, you may replace `Line[]` with `Arrow[]` if you want the vector to have an arrow

Comment: Thank you egwene! :) Just what I needed. I understand how to do it now!