# Remove controls in Animate with exception of PlayPauseButton

Tags: animation, gui-construction

I'd like to retain the `PlayPauseButton` in the `Animate` and remove all other `Controls` available by default. 
I've looked at [How can I completely remove the ListAnimate controls?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13024/how-can-i-completely-remove-the-listanimate-controls), but haven't had success with these methods in my complex example.

This works:

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 0, 5}, 
  AnimationRunning -> False] /. 
 HoldPattern[
   AppearanceElements -> _] -> (AppearanceElements -> \
{"PlayPauseButton"})
```

but this does not:

```
Dynamic@Animate[
If[j == 1, Clear[DataTable2, DataTable3]; DataTable2 = {}; 
 DataTable3 = {}]; 
AppendTo[DataTable2, {steps[[2, 1, j]], f@steps[[2, 1, j]]}];
AppendTo[DataTable3, {steps[[2, 1, j]], steps[[2, 1, j]]}]; 
AppendTo[DataTable3, {steps[[2, 1, j]], f@steps[[2, 1, j]]}];
Dynamic@
 Plot[{f[x], y = x}, {x, interval[[1]], interval[[2]]}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style[StringForm["``. The orbit of x is\n``\n", explanation, 
     textCell], 12, TextAlignment -> Center], 
  ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 1}}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
  ImagePadding -> 25, PlotRange -> {interval[[1]], interval[[2]]},
   AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, 
  Epilog -> {Gray, Line[DataTable3], Black, PointSize[0.015], 
    Point@{DataTable2}, Red, PointSize[0.015], 
    Point@{steps[[2, 1, j]], f@steps[[2, 1, j]]}}], {j, locate, 
 Length[steps[[2, 1]]], 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True, 
AnimationRunning -> False, LabelStyle -> White] ]]/. 
 HoldPattern[
   AppearanceElements -> _] -> (AppearanceElements -> \
{"PlayPauseButton"})
```

Comment: You haven't accepted an answer, so why don't you post a code sample that runs, with all necessary variables defined?  You could cut down this code until it has the minimum features needed to illustrate the problem.  Or if you've already solved the problem, it would be nice to see your solution, and you can accept your own answer if it's the best one.

Answer (score 5):

Put your options inside your control (you don't need those cumbersome constructions with patterns and Dynamic@Animate):

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[x + a], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> 0], {{a, 0, ""}, 0, 5,
   AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton"}, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I've resorted to 'Dynamic', since I'm using an outside 'Manipulate' which restarts the animation each time a variable gets changed from free form input. Adding , AppearanceElements -> "PlayPauseButton" did nothing.