# Prohibiting Autorun in a Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate

One of the four possible `AppearanceElements` for `Manipulate` is "ManipulateMenu" which provides a number of features such as bookmarks, pasting snapshots, autorun, etc.

I'd like to have some of the elements of the Manipulate menu, but not all of them. In particular, I'd like to remove `Autorun`, as it is not useful or interesting in my application. In fact it is positively undesirable. Is it possible to edit the menu, in particular to remove unwanted items? The documentation suggests not.

Alternatively, is it possible to disable `Autorun`?  I've tried `AutorunSequencing -> {}` and `AutorunSequencing -> None` but they appear to do nothing (and are not documented).

Comment: `AppearanceElements -> {"HideControlsButton", "SnapshotButton", 
  "ResetButton", "UpdateButton", "HideControlsButton"}`? take a look at [46792](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46792/5478) too.

Comment: @Kuba well that's an idea (but not having `"HideControlButton"` twice :-) but it does look horrible on my system (the little buttons, I mean) and doesn't give access to the Bookmarks facility of `"ManipulateMenu"`.  And thanks for reminding me to update the information on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46792/4811 !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can effectively disable `Autorun` by adding the option

```
AutorunSequencing -> {Automatic, 0}
```

to your `Manipulate`. The auto-run control will still pop up, but it won't do anything.