# How to display movie without controls

Tags: image, animation

I would like to display a sequence of images as a movie within mathematica. I am aware of ListAnimate, but I do not want the various controls included, and there seems to be no way to remove them.

Comment: Perhaps you can use the example in [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16903/245).

Comment: Since @Jens linked answer has a lot of nice information, the function that answers this question is `makeAnimation`

Comment: see also [how can I completely remove ListAnimate controls](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13024/125)

Comment: The answers were useful, but all require clever, obscure syntax. It seems odd that with all the native capabilities of mathematica, this one is absent. Perhaps some day in the future there will be a "Movie" object with a status similar to "Image."

Comment: This is a minimal example that seems to work. movie is a list of images. Dynamic[movie[[Clock[{1, 8, 1}, 4, 1]]]]

Comment: A more complete but still minimal function:
ShowMovie[movie_, framerate_, cycles_: 1] := Module[
  {frames, seconds},
  frames = Length[movie];
  seconds = frames/framerate;
  Dynamic[movie[[Clock[{1, frames, 1}, seconds, cycles]]]]]

Answer (score 2):

For variety, one can do this with `ControllerManipulate`

```
imgs = Plot[Sin[x + #], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/10];
ControllerManipulate[
 Show[imgs[[(Pause[0.05]; 1 + Mod[x++, Length@imgs - 0])]]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't carefully looked over the `makeAnimation` that is suggested in the comments but it looks like it might be even be more advanced than what you need, it certainly is more advanced that what I had written so here goes a basic version that might help you:

```
animation[frames_, delay_] := Module[{fr = frames},
  Dynamic[
   Refresh[First[fr = RotateRight@fr], UpdateInterval -> delay], 
   TrackedSymbols -> {}
   ]
  ]
```

Example usage:

```
frames = Table[Graphics[{ColorData["Rainbow"]@RandomReal[], Rectangle[]}], {10}];
animation[frames, 0.5]
```

The second argument says that it should switch frame every 0.5 seconds.