# How can I make an animated demonstration of the Wigner semicircle distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, animation

With *Mathematica* 10, it's possible to draw the semicircle distribution of R. Wigner:

```
data = RandomVariate[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1, 3], 10^4];

Show[
  Histogram[data, 20, "PDF"],
  Plot[PDF[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1, 3], x], {x, -2, 4}, PlotStyle -> Thick]]
```

[image: Wignersemicircledistribution]

My question is: how can I make an animated version of Wigner semicircle distribution as shown below?

[image]

Comment: What *is* the question? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Yves Klett How to get this image in mathematica 10

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect that. Also, if you show what you already tried, you might get more answers.

Comment: Ok, serious now, do you want to export gif? Have a loop with precalculated frames? Dynamic random frame? Interactive Manipualte?

Comment: `data := RandomVariate[WignerSemicircleDistribution[0, 1], 10^2];

Dynamic[
 
 
 
 Show[
  Histogram[data, 10, "PDF"], 
  Plot[PDF[WignerSemicircleDistribution[0, 1], x], {x, -2, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> Thick]
  ,
  PlotRange -> 2]
 ,
 UpdateInterval -> .2]`

Comment: Thank for your patience. It's work thank's to Kuba help.

Comment: Special Thank to Kuba for his gracious help.

Comment: Since it is not clear whether an exported `GIF` is also desired, or just an embedded movie, I would say this could be a duplicate of [Is it possible to insert an animated image into Mathematica notebook?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3037/245). The workflow would simply be to first create a `GIF` from within *Mathematica*, then re-import that using the function `makeAnimation` in my answer. That function fixes a bug which leads to a hard crash when you right-click on the animation created using `Kuba`'s method (in version 8).

Comment: To illustrate the workflow I just described, see my answer to [How to create animated snowfall?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16903/245)

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of other how-to-animate-X question; I recommend that an original be found and it be marked as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data := RandomVariate[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1, 3], 10^4];

Dynamic[
 Clock[{0, 5, 1}, 1]; 
 Histogram[data, 20, "PDF", 
  ChartStyle -> EdgeForm[White],
  Axes -> False, 
  PlotRange -> {{-4, 6}, {0, .25}}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, 
  Frame -> True,
  Epilog- > 
      First[Plot[PDF[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1, 3], x], {x, -4, 6}, 
        PlotStyle -> Thick]]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Kuba answered this question in a comment, but I think it needs to be recorded as a formal answer.

You can animate your static plot by wrapping it with [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) and supplying the option [`UpdateInterval`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpdateInterval.html).

```
data := RandomVariate[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1, 3], 10^4];
Dynamic[
  Show[
    Histogram[data, 20, "PDF"], 
    Plot[PDF[WignerSemicircleDistribution[1, 3], x], {x, -2, 4}, PlotStyle -> Thick]],
  UpdateInterval -> .5]
```

The output will look exactly like the static plot you show in your question, but it will update every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Just a warning: Unfortunately, this crashes (in version 8) when you right-click on the animation. See [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16903/245) where I work around this problem in the function `makeAnimation`.

Comment: The crash bug has been fixed in version 10. But in version 8, don't use this, or the user will lose all their unsaved changes in the crash.