# Simulation of the semicircle Wigner Theorem

Tags: simulation

Let's begin  with some termes:

1. For $1\le i<j<\infty$ let $X_{i,j}$ be independant and indentically
   distributed (i.i.d) real random variables with mean $0$ and variance
   $1$ and set $X_{j,i}=X_{i,j}$. Let $X_{i,i}$ be i.i.d. real random
   variables (with possibly a different distribution) with mean $0$ and
   variance $1$. Then $M_n=\left[ X_{i,j}\right]_{i,j=1}^n$ will be a
   random $n\times n$ symmetric matrix.

---

2. There are $n$ random eigenvalues which we will denote by $$
   \lambda_1\le \lambda_2\le \dots \lambda_n. $$ The empirical spectral
   measure is $$ \nu^*_n=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{\lambda_i}. $$
   This is a random discrete probability measure which puts $n^{-1}$
   mass to each (random) eigenvalue.

---

3. **theorem:(Wigner's semicircle law)**  Let $$ \nu_n=\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{\frac{\lambda_i}{\sqrt{n}}}. $$ be the
   normalized empirical spectral measure. Then as $n\to \infty$ we have
   $$ \nu_n \Rightarrow \nu \qquad \text{a.s.} $$ where $\nu$ has
   density 
   $$ 
     \frac{d\nu}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\pi} \sqrt{4-x^2}\,\chi_{\{|x|\le 2\}}.
      $$ ($\chi_A$ denote the indicatrice function of $A$)

---

**Question** Using simulation to understand this theorem in other word: Do the same thing that was done for the central limit theorem as it is shown in this page  [CLT](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheCentralLimitTheorem/) 
I have already posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75711/how-can-i-make-an-animated-demonstration-of-the-wigner-semicircle-distribution)
 about the same subject.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the linked question, you already seem to have a simulation. So what is the *Mathematica* issue you want to address here?

Comment: My question is to do the same thing that was done for the central limit theorem as it is shown in this page http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheCentralLimitTheorem/