# How to keep the animation auto-run when I hide control bar

Tags: animation

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}, 
 ControlType -> None,AnimationRunning -> True]
```

[image]

Will give me a static graphic,How to keep the animation running?

Comment: @YvesKlett Thanks.I have tried that before I post this. :)

Comment: Do you want to open it at all? `Dynamic@Panel@Plot[Sin[x (1 + Clock[2] x)], {x, 0, 6}]`

Comment: @Kuba Amazing!!This not my original idea,but I think this deserve to post a answer.

Comment: If you want a continuously running animation that doesn't have the empty space of the `Animate` panel above it, I would use `makeAnimation[Table[Plot[Sin[x (1+a x)],{x,0,6}],{a,0,2,.1}],{.05}]`, using [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30468/245).

Comment: @Jens Wow,thanks for your link~