# Resizing Imported GIF Image

Tags: notebooks, image, animation, gif-format

I have a gif image that I am trying to import into the Mathematica Notebook, and I found the accepted answer of this question very useful: [Is it possible to insert an animated image into Mathematica notebook?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3037/is-it-possible-to-insert-an-animated-image-into-mathematica-notebook)

So, I am typing:

```
Import["myimage.gif", "Animation"]
```

The problem is that now I want to resize it .. It is possible to drag and resize an individual image

[image]

But if I move the slider, now I have to resize every single of all the images that compose the GIF Image

[image]

How do I resize the whole animation?

Answer (score 1):

You can first import the list of resized images (using `ImageSize` option for GIF Import) and then animate it with `ListAnimate`:

```
ListAnimate @ Import["myimage.gif", ImageSize -> {100, 200}]
```

Notice that

```
Import["myimage.gif", "Animation", ImageSize -> {100, 200}]
```

will not work because in this case `ImageSize` affects the animation window size and not the image itself.